# How to add an image watermark in PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdfsharp

All samples show how to add a text watermark using PDFsharp. but what if I need to add an image watermark?

I did this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_logo) && System.IO.File.Exists(_logo))
{
    XImage logo = XImage.FromFile(_logo);
    XRect rectLogo = new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
    rectLogo.Scale(0.5, 0.5);
    gfx.DrawImage(logo, rectLogo);
}
```

The image appears, but not as a watermark.

EDIT:

I have finally placed a watermark manually, however,there is another thing to solve. How to change opacity of an XImage? I can do it by using an image processor but that is not the idea. This is a software that will use a normal user, and I cannot tell him to modify the image before assigning it as the watermark. Any solution to this?

This is the code at the moment:

```
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_logo) && System.IO.File.Exists(_logo))
            {
                XImage logo = XImage.FromFile(_logo);
                double width = logo.PointWidth;
                double height = logo.PointHeight;
                double ratio = width / height;
                if (width > page.Width.Point * 0.5)
                {
                    width = page.Width.Point * 0.5;
                    height = width / ratio;
                }
                else if (height > page.Height.Point * 0.5)
                {
                    height = page.Height.Point * 0.5;
                    width = height * ratio;
                }

                double offsetX = (page.Width.Point - width) / 2;
                double offsetY = (page.Height.Point - height) / 2;

                XRect rectLogo = new XRect(offsetX, offsetY, width, height);
                gfx.DrawImage(logo, rectLogo);
            }
```

Comment: You don't tell us what you expect, you don't tell us what you need. Drawing the image like you do looks like the correct approach, but it may need some tweaking to get the optimal result.

Comment: What you comment is not necessary to specify if you know what a watermark is. My appoach just places an image in front of text. Of course I need it to be placed behind text and with less opacity. If you know Microsoft Word you can know exactly what I need if you see its watermark option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual the computer does what you tell him to do, not what you want him to do.

If you want to have the image below other contents, then draw it first.

If you want to have a semi-transparent image, then use a transparent image or draw it with transparency. In that case you may place the image above all other contents of the page.

Comment: Thanks...you have given me a clue. I have drawn the image before the text and I am almost there. I have modified the question that explain the problem to solve now. I need to change opacity to the image. Is it possible with PdfSharp? or maybe I can do it with System.Drawing.Image object and then load it in XImage using XImage.FromGdiPlusImage

Comment: I'm afraid there is no documented way to draw images with transparency (there was a bug that allowed doing this, but the bug is fixed with current internal builds). Hack: Draw the image and draw a white rectangle with transparency over the image. I think it's cleaner to use System.Drawing.Image to do the trick. Call FromGdiPlusImage only once and use it for all pages to avoid having multiple copies of the image in your PDF. No problem with FromFile, but FromGdiPlusImage may lead to multiple copies.

Comment: Finally I did that way. I changed opacity with System.Drawing.Image and it works perfectly now.

Comment: A computer is a `him`...really?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Is a computer a He or a She? https://sharenator.com/Is_a_Computer_a_He_or_a_She/

Answer (score 2):

The problem with PDFSharp's Watermark samples is the fact that they're not using the real watermark functionality introduced in `PDF 1.6` version ([reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)). The samples use the `XGraphics` object to draw beneath the existing content but it's just a fake watermark. Here's a direct quote from the documentation:

> Note: Technically the watermarks in this sample are simple graphical output. They have nothing to do with the Watermark Annotations introduced in PDF 1.5.

*Please notice that the official reference by Adobe says that Watermark annotations were introduced in PDF 1.6, so there seems to be an error in PDFSharp's documentation.*

Unfortunately, I don't have a reliable source whether or not PDFSharp supports *real* watermarks, but I haven't seen any proof that they do. The fact is that `PDF 1.4` version is fully supported and everything above it is only partially supported.